# Carousel is null on web page in Stencil theme

Tags: bigcommerce

When creating a custom Page Template for use as Home Page, "Display as Home Page
Yes, display this page as the home page of my store " the "carousel" data element is null, making it impossible to use stencil CLI. Is there a work-around for this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to be sure to include `carousel: true` in the front matter for your page.html template. The custom template you create will pick up its context from page.html. Hope that helps!